# Как найти все зависимости perl скрипта?

Tags: perl

Есть сервер на `perl`, часть файлов этого сервера используются клиентом-скриптом, расположенным в той же папке что и сервер.

Как мне в папке найти все файлы, необходимые для запуска и работы скрипта-клиента и отбросить ненужные файлы, которые использует только сервер, а не клиент?

Comment: [похожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811643/how-to-visualise-code-dependencies-for-perl-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для начала надо найти все модули утилитой `scandeps` и выгрузить в файл

```
scandeps.pl -V *.pm > moduls.txt
```

далее нам в файле надо оставить только имена файлов, соответствующие модулям, в каждой строке удалить все что идет перед `/`

```
perl -pi -e 's/.*\///g' modules.txt
```

И осуществить поиск всех этих файлов

```
while read in; do sudo find -n "$in"; done < modules.txt
```